# Why does Eclipse keep (a) jar(s) in the target folder open?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

I'm working on a project and I try to run (outside of Eclipse, in cygwin (thus Windows environment)):

```
mvn clean
```

which fails because of:

`org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4:clean (default-clean) on project *****: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete path_to_project\target\org.apache-    commons-httpclient-3.1.jar ->` [Help 1]

I know it's eclipse keeping the jar opened. When I clean my projects in Eclipse before I run the maven command, the error doesn't occur (obviously Eclipse cleans the target folders).

Comment: Bad idea to run Windows Maven from Cygwin - it doesn't respond correctly to Ctrl-C, and there are other problems. Use the Windows `cmd` instead IMHO, or something like Console2

Comment: I'Ve got similar situations, I think it's because of Eclipse recognizing  file system changes and starting a build/scan parallel to your cmd call.

Answer (score 2):

This happens, for example, when you run Maven on Windows outside of Eclipse and Eclipse is configured to refresh the workspace automatically.

What happens is that Maven starts to change files in the workspace and Eclipse notices and tried to see what is happening. If the two accidentally happen to try to access the same file, one of them loses. Usually, it's Maven (because Eclipse just logs an error and continues).

You can disable the automatic refresh while Maven runs or switch to "Refresh on Access" if you have Eclipse 3.7.